# How to create a clickable span between the text in a div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

There is an existing html div with text inside. I wish to modify the contents of the div with additional text, but with a span of text (B) in between the existing text (A) and what I am inserting (C). The span also has a css style implemented by id, but removed from code snippet as it does not directly matter.

If the span was to be at the very end, I could simply append the span as a child, which would put it at the end of the div text. However any text I later add to the div will still come before the span. The span will always be at the end, at least as far as I know.

Let us say existing div says "Hello World. " I wish to use Javascript to add the following:

```
var targetDiv = div;
div.textContent = 'Hello World! ';
var spanText = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
spanText.innerHTML = 'Click Me!';
spanText.onclick = function(){
  perform task here;
};
div.textContent += ' Did you click it?';
```

The div would not show "Hello World. Click Me! Did you click it?" It would show "Hello World.  Did you click it?Click Me!"

I've tried making the span inside the div using innerHTML when appending the text, such that it is like below:

```
var targetDiv = div;
div.textContent = 'Hello World! ';
targetDiv.innerHTML += '<span>Click Me!</span> Did you click it?';
var spanText = div.span; //and variations such as div.children(1);
spanText.onclick = function(){
  perform task here;
};
```

The problem here is that I'm guessing since it is in innerHTML, javascript does not recognize/find the span, so it cannot be assigned a variable name. Or assign onclicks and stuff onto it. Here, the text does display correctly, as "Hello World. Click Me! Did you click it?", but the onclick does not work. So I tried putting the onclick function (yes, a one-liner) inside the innerHTML as below:

```
var targetDiv = div;
div.textContent = 'Hello World! ';
targetDiv.innerHTML += '<span onclick = "perform task here;">Click Me!</span> Did you click it?';
```

This did not work either. Unlike the first and similar to the second attempt, text displays correctly but function does not work.

As for why I'm doing such a pointless exercise, this is simply an abstracted example of what I'm working on, and I felt that uploading the actual code in this case would only bog it down with needless context. However I am ready to provide any clarification if any is needed.

Vanilla JS please. I don't have JQuery on my project at the moment and putting it in for such a minor piece of code seems like overkill.

Assistance would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `textContent`, use [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) and `appendChild`, see `***` lines:

```
var targetDiv = div;
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World! '));      // ***
var spanText = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
spanText.innerHTML = 'Click Me!'; // Could use `createTextNode` here as well...
spanText.onclick = function(){
  // perform task here;
};
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' Did you click it?')); // ***
```

Live Example:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello World! '));
var spanText = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
spanText.innerHTML = 'Click Me!'; // Could use `createTextNode` here as well...
spanText.onclick = function(){
  console.log("Clicked!");
};
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' Did you click it?'));

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Of course, another approach is to use `innerHTML` and then get the span afterward:

```
div.innerHTML = "Hello World! <span>Click Me!</span> Did you click it?";
div.querySelector("span").onclick = function(){
  console.log("Clicked!");
};
```

Live Example:

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.innerHTML = "Hello World! <span>Click Me!</span> Did you click it?";
div.querySelector("span").onclick = function(){
  console.log("Clicked!");
};

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: yes, the second solution is short, neat and simple! And I just implemented it and it works as expected! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Terrornado - If you ever need to insert something like this into an **existing** element's text (e.g., instead of when building it as per above), you'd use [`splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText) on the text node. Just FWIW. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha that splitText method is a gem and something that I honestly didn't know existed. I've spent a lot of time writing simple parsing client-side over the last few years( for micro-templating or creating a basic custom syntax highlighter)  and I'm a little embarrassed because I can't believe that I never came across that one. +1

Answer (score 1):

Good news! There's a JavaScript method for this already. A few actually.

[`element.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and [`element.insertAdjacentText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText) are methods that allow you to position `text` and `html` before, after, and as a first child or last child of the specified element.

The first parameter takes a position value. Those can be any one of the following:

```
'beforebegin': Before the element itself.
'afterbegin': Just inside the element, before its first child.
'beforeend': Just inside the element, after its last child.
'afterend': After the element itself.
```

The second parameter is either the `text` or `HTML` you would like to insert at the specified position.

As an example of what this would look like in general:

```
 let element = document.querySelector("div"); //get a div element!

 element.insertAdjacentText("beforeend",
"this text node is the last child of the div");

 element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", 
"<span>Just kidding, This span tag is now the last child of the div! </span>");

 element.insertAdjacentText("beforebegin", 
 "This text is inserted directly before the div!");

 element.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", 
 "<span> This span tag is now the first child of the div!</span>");

 element.insertAdjacentText("afterend",
"This text is entered directly after the closing div tag!");
```

In your use case ( though I agree with T.J Crowder about it being best to insert the span tag by creating a node and appending it instead of using `innerHTML` - *reason being it has better performance and provides more clarity*, I'll leave that to your discretion), the following example will give you an idea of how to apply these methods to your code:

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div");
div.innerHTML = "<span> click me </span>";
let span = div.querySelector("span");

span.addEventListener("click", function() {
alert("clicked span");
});


span.insertAdjacentText("beforebegin", " ::this is before the span tag::");
span.insertAdjacentText("afterend", " ::this is after the span tag:: ");

/*
'beforebegin': Before the element itself.
'afterbegin': Just inside the element, before its first child.
'beforeend': Just inside the element, after its last child.
'afterend': After the element itself.
*/
```

```css
span {
color: red;
cursor: pointer;
}

div {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```